# Store javascript object inside a GA event value or an event label?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters

I know GA event can store event label and value. However, when I tried to store a stringified object into value, it seems not showing anything at all. So is it a good idea to store the object(stringified) inside GA event `label` instead since the value does not store object nor stringified object?

Or, maybe there is another field I can store objects or... long strings of data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Event Attributes such as Category, Action and Label must be strings. No other data type is supported.

There's no way to store Javascript Objects in Google Analytics.

They do have a [max size documented](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#events) of 150 bytes for Categories and 500 bytes for Actions and Labels. But I find you can store longer values as long as the [maximum size of the request is within the 8k documented size](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#using-post). If your hit is larger than that it simply won't be sent to Google Analytics.

But I would recommend that you just store a string with 500 bytes to stay within documented limits as these can start to be enforced at any time.

If you need to store larger blobs of data the best idea is to do that in your database and just send a string with the database primary key to GA, so you can join this data later. Another option is to split the object into multiple strings and send each one as its own separate hit scoped [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) when you send the event.

Comment: store a string with 500 bytes to stay within documented limits  indicate I should store such data in the label correct? seems its the best way. since category and action does not make sense. thought? @Eduardo